# How do I undo an override of a clojure core function?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning some clojure. I accidentally overrode a core method in clojure: seq. The line of code I ran was:

`(def seq "WATCH OUT!")`

I then got a warning in the console:

`WARNING: seq already refers to: #'clojure.core/seq in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/seq`

Now the value of the `seq` is `WATCH OUT!`.

How do I undo this? And isn't this rather a dangerous power? Couldn't one theoretically break a program this way?

Comment: You can just re-import `seq`: `(require '[clojure.core :refer [seq]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you've defined a `seq` symbol in your own namespace, making `seq` inaccessible without explicitly specifying the namespace to look it up.

To check if that's the case, try this after "blowing `seq` up":

```clj
(clojure.core/seq [1 2 3])
```

If that works (outputs `(1 2 3)`), the solution is to [`refer`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/refer) it again from `clojure.core`, as done by default:

```clj
(refer 'clojure.core :only ['seq])
```

Or, [a shorthand](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/refer-clojure) for this specific namespace:

```clj
(refer-clojure :only ['seq])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `refer`ing the var after defining it in a namespace will not work, since there is a compiler safeguard.

You can unmap the var to be able to `refer` the name again:

`(ns-unmap *ns* 'seq)
(refer-clojure)`